# Check if string is in a list

Tags: python, list, input

I've seen many solutions of this type of problem but I can't really find one that I'm looking for.

For example:

```
text = ['hi', 'hello', 'hey']
user_input = input('Enter something: ')

for word in user_input:
    if word in text:
        print('Hi')
    else:
        print('Bye')
```

If the `user_input` was "hi there", it would give me back

```
Bye
Bye
Bye
Bye
Bye
Bye
Bye
Bye
```

How can I check to see if at least one of the words in `user_input` is in the list (text)?

Comment: `word` loops over the characters of the string `user_input`.

Comment: You have to split your `user_input` into words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
text = ['hi', 'hello', 'hey']
user_input = input('Enter something: ')

for word in user_input.split(" "):
    if word in text:
        print('Hi')
    else:
        print('Bye')
```

**Another Option:**

```
text = ['hi', 'hello', 'hey']
user_input = input('Enter something: ')

flag = "Y"
for word in user_input.split(" "):
    if word in text:
        print('Matched String:', word)
    else:
        flag = "N"

if flag == "N":
    print("Unmatched String Exists")
```

Comment: Split the input into multiple words !

Comment: It does work in the fact that it prints 'Hi' when I write a string that is in the list. But it also prints "Bye" for every string NOT in the list

Comment: do you want a single "Bye" message?

Comment: I'm sorry. I got the answer. This is perfect. I can just do 'pass' for the else thank you!

Comment: thanks for your note, please vote-up if you liked the solution !

Answer (score 1):

in addition to the others answer, two more options:

1. using `.index()`
2. using a filter in `pandas.DataFrame`

Option 2 is advantageous as it shows all hits, while option 1 only shows the first hit but is more "pythonic".

Option 1:

```
text = ['hi', 'hello', 'hey']
user_input = input('Enter something: ')

try:
    text.index(user_input)
    print('Hi')
except ValueError:
    print('Bye')
```

`try...except` is implemented due to the problem that .index() drops an error in the case that the search string is not in the list.

Option 2:

```
import pandas as pd
text = ['hi', 'hello', 'hey']
user_input = input('Enter something: ')
df=pd.DataFrame(text)
result=df[df[0]==user_input]
if len(result)>0: 
    print('Hi')
    [print(result[i]) for i in range(len(result))]
else:
    print('Bye')
```